# How to configure the path in LookupRecord NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, lookup

I have a Json file in my database, the structure is like this:

```
{
 "employeeId": "ref-123",
 "name": "Danie",
 "manager": {
    "employeeId": "ref-456",
    "name": "John"
  }
}
```

I want to do a lookup in the lookupRecord to let it find the manager name based on the manager Id. Here is the configuration of the lookupRecord.

I added a customer property which is employeeId, and the path is /manager/employeeId. But I cannot get the the name (which is John).

So how can I configure the path, because the value I want to find is embedded in the "manager".

[image]

Comment: Could you please share a picture of your flow?

Comment: @Pdeuxa, my flow is GenerateFlowFile to generate file, like {
"manager": {
    "employeeId": "ref-45f"
}
}, and use LookupRecord. In LookupRecord is JsonReader and JsonWriter. I want to do the enrichment,  find the name in the manager level. like this{
"manager": {
    "employeeId": "ref-456",
    "name": "John"
  }}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using mongoDB, for the lookupService.

I reproduced your flow:

- generateFlowFile :  { "manager": { "employeeId": "ref-123" } }
- LookupRecord[image: LookupRecord]

**ResultRecord Path**, where you want to put the lookup result in your flowfile.

**employeeid**, what to look for in your flowFile and send it to the lookup service.

On mongodb side, I have the following document :

```json
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5fb6932c01e6ef0027e0af5b" }, 
  "employeeId" : "ref-123", 
  "name" : "Danie", 
  "manager" : 
          { "employeeId" : "ref-456", "name" : "John" } }
```

Lookup service is configured as the following (if you use mongodb):
[image: Lookup service]

Finally I have this output :

```json
[{"manager":{"employeeId":"ref-123","name":"Danie"}}]
```

Tell me if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you. But the name I want to get is inside of the manager, which is { "manager": { "employeeId": "ref-456" } }  in the generate file. Output should be [{"manager":{ "employeeId" : "ref-456", "name" : "John" }}]. But when I try to do this, it get the  [{"manager":{ "employeeId" : "ref-456", "name" : "Danie" }}]. The name should be John. I think it's kind of ambiguous, because the file has two same element name "name". How to fix it without changing the name "name"?

Comment: I just change the name inside of the manager, "manager": {
    "managerId": "ref-3",
    "managerName": "John"
  }. But it cannot find the name "John", and return null. So this Mongodb can only do the simple key-value pair search?